# An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in Ninject.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

I am following the Pro ASP.Net MVC5 book by Adam Freeman. I have created the sportsStore project as per the chapter 7. And after creating the project templates and adding the references, I build the project and try to debug it. I get this pop-up box[image]

And if I click on cancel, I get the exception mentioned in the question. I am not able to figure this out. Any suggestions

[image]

I get the above error when I click on cancel.

Here is the call stack of the exception -

```
Ninject.dll!Ninject.Modules.AssemblyNameRetriever.GetAssemblyNames(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> filenames, System.Predicate<System.Reflection.Assembly> filter) Line 54   C#
Ninject.dll!Ninject.Modules.CompiledModuleLoaderPlugin.LoadModules(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> filenames) Line 81    C#
Ninject.dll!Ninject.Modules.ModuleLoader.LoadModules(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> patterns) Line 54   C#
Ninject.dll!Ninject.KernelBase.Load(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> filePatterns) Line 237   C#
Ninject.dll!Ninject.KernelBase.KernelBase(Ninject.Components.IComponentContainer components, Ninject.INinjectSettings settings, Ninject.Modules.INinjectModule[] modules) Line 100  C#
Ninject.dll!Ninject.KernelBase.KernelBase(Ninject.Modules.INinjectModule[] modules) Line 60 C#
Ninject.dll!Ninject.StandardKernel.StandardKernel(Ninject.Modules.INinjectModule[] modules) Line 48 C#
```

> SportsStore.WebUI.dll!SportsStore.WebUI.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon.CreateKernel() Line 38   C#
>       Ninject.Web.Common.dll!Ninject.Web.Common.Bootstrapper.Initialize(System.Func createKernelCallback) Line 50    C#
>       SportsStore.WebUI.dll!SportsStore.WebUI.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon.Start() Line 23  C#
>       [External Code] 
>   . 
>   I understand that the AssemblyNameRetriever class is missing and I did try to fix it by downloading it from github and using that class. But again it gives some exceptions. Shouldn't the Ninject take care of this class by itself.

Comment: can you please post the additional information you are getting from the exception ?

Comment: This might help, it might not: Hit Ctrl+Alt+E, choose "thrown" under "common language runtime exceptions". This might help you in pinpointing your error.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your exception, you are trying to load Mvc Version **3.0.0.0**. You are currently running a different Mvc version.

If you have the source code to the projects that depend on the older Mvc version, you can try to re-compile them with the newer version. You can also try messing with the dependencies to have the right version across the board.

There is also a [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/705289/An-exception-of-type-System-IO-FileLoadException-o) page with a person with a similar situation. [The author writes](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/706959/An-exception-of-type-System-IO-FileLoadException-o):

> After reviewing the code pes1957 sent to me I was able to determine that there was indeed an assembly reference error.
>
> Basically the number of projects that were in the solution had a mixture of version 5 and 6 Entity Framework references. I updated the references, and web.config to show the correct version number and all compiles correctly.

Comment: While adding references to my project I had added System.Web.Mvc version 4.0.0.0. I dont understand why is it taking 3.0.0.0 while loading

Comment: It must be the other assembly (Ninject) that requires the older version. You could try to find a newer version of the assembly to use.

Comment: I have installed the following packages through Nuget package manager: 1. Ninject- the version doesn't show up in package manager. Theres just one package called Ninject and I have installed it.                           2. Ninject.Web.Common - same as Ninject. No version mentioned. Just one package listed.                                                             3. Ninject.MVC5. Now this is supposed to be compatible with MVC5.    I do not know which package among these 3 is causing the trouble. One of these is trying to load System.Web.Mvc 3.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

The same problem occured in my project. It seems that installing NInject from nuget package as first one caused the Ninject library wants System.Web.MVC v3. After uninstalling all Ninject library from nuget package manager and adding NInject.MVC5 package as the first and only package, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue and turned out my MVC web project was referencing another MVC Web API project, Ninject error was coming from the Web API project. In my case I removed the reference to keep things simple.